# Won't I lose my Windows 10 license if I restore Windows 8.1 from backup

Tags: windows-10, windows-8.1, backup, restore

I have a computer the drivers are mostly Windows-only, and Windows 10 runs like crap on it - performance-wise.

I'd like to get Windows 8.1 back by restoring from Clonezilla backup. I have some worries, though

- Will there be no problems with the Windows 8.1 license becoming invalid due to the fact I upgraded to Windows 10
- Will there be no license problems if I make a Clonezilla copy of Windows 10 right now, restore Windows 10 right now, restore Windows 8.1 from backup and, later, restore W10 back again?
- Is it true that no drivers ever will be released for Windows 8.1, so new hardware won't run on Windows 8.1?

The computer came with an OEM license.

Comment: You will not, the license you recieved, was licensed to the machine itself.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you’ve upgraded within the last month, you can uninstall Windows 10 and downgrade your PC back to its original Windows 7 or Windows 8.1 operating system. You can always upgrade to Windows 10 again later.

Even if it’s been more than a month, you should be able to reinstall the version of Windows that came with your PC using fresh installation media and its product key.

If you’ve upgraded a PC to Windows 10 — not performed a clean install, but an upgrade — you’ll have an easy option that lets you revert to the last version of Windows. To access this, open the Start menu and select Settings. Click the “Update & security” icon and select “Recovery.”

You should see a “Go back to Windows 7” or “Go back to Windows 8.1” option. Click the Get started button to get rid of your Windows 10 install and restore your previous Windows install. Microsoft will ask you why you want to go back.
The above is from [this HowToGeek Article](http://www.howtogeek.com/220723/how-to-uninstall-windows-10-and-downgrade-to-windows-7-or-8.1/). (Click the link for more information.)

**About your specific questions.**

> Will there be no problems with the Windows 8.1 license becoming
>   invalid due to the fact I upgraded to Windows 10?

No, if you have a valid windows 8.1 key, it should remain valid regardless of "upgrading" to windows 10.

> Will there be no license problems if I make a Clonezilla copy of Windows 10 right now, restore Windows 10 right now, restore Windows 8.1 from backup and, later, restore W10 back again?

Probably not, the "free" windows 10 upgrade uses your 8.1 activation key, if they decide to stop accepting those keys you'll probably need to buy a new one.

> Is it true that no drivers ever will be released for Windows 8.1, so new hardware won't run on Windows 8.1?

No, and yes. Think of it this way, you still have at least another 10 years before windows stops supporting windows 7 and 8.1, and device manufactures know most of the computers out run older operating system. I wouldn't worry about this.

Comment: Please fix your formatting for readability.

Comment: That better? Sorry for initial response. Rough day in the office.

Comment: I thought you might ask that... I'll clarify.

Comment: No need, I think I found the issue. Read edit.

Comment: Oh, I just removed some redundant formatting, without reading your comment. I looked for a meta post about formatting without finding one (but I'll ask around).

Comment: No worries, I appreciate the help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41735/discussion-between-wizlog-and-bigelittles).

Answer (score 1):

No, there should not be any problem using your key if you downgrade to Windows 8.1 from your backup. As far as making a copy of your current Windows 10 and then reinstalling from an image later on, there shouldn't be any license problems with that either. This is all assuming you don't try to use the Windows 8.1 image on one computer and the Windows 10 one on another one at the same time. In that case, it may cause issues.

I don't know where you heard the claim of no drivers will ever be released for Windows 8.1. Wherever you heard it, it is false. For one thing, Windows 8.1 does not end it's mainstream support until January 9th, 2018. And it's extended support doesn't end until January 10th, 2023.

> End of support refers to the date when Microsoft no longer provides automatic fixes, updates, or online technical assistance.

Just as an example that new hardware still has drivers written for Windows 8.1, you could look at the new Nvidia cards, the GTX 1070 and GTX 1080. Both of those cards have drivers for Windows 7, 8, 8.1, and Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the Windows licence code is hardcoded into the motherboard. So even after multiple system formats or change of OS the licence is not altered and is restored when you install windows 10.

If you want to be on safe side you can always backup your product key using the method mentioned in the link.

[How to Find Your Lost Windows or Office Product Keys](http://www.howtogeek.com/206329/how-to-find-your-lost-windows-or-office-product-keys/)